# Replacement in a list with assigning a weight

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, set

My question has two parts: First, suppose we have a list of elements:

```
l=['x1','x2','x3','x4']
```

How do you assign a weight to each element? for example, in the beginning, all elements have weight one. My second part of the question is to take two elements in random mix them and make a new element. So the new list would be:

```
l=['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5']
```

where 'x5' now has weight two as: 'x5'= 'x1'+'x3' for example.

What I have so far is

```
def randMerge(l:list, count:int) -> list:
return l + [random.sample(l,k=count)]

def flatten(d):
    return [i for b in [[c] if not isinstance(c, list) else flatten(c)
            for c in d] for i in b]

num = 2
aList = ['x1','x2','x3','x4']

res = []
newList = aList[:]

for _ in range(3):
    newList = randMerge(newList,num)
    print(newList)
```

which has a output as:

```
#['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', ['x2', 'x3']]
#['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', ['x2', 'x3'], ['x2', 'x4']]
#['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', ['x2', 'x3'], ['x2', 'x4'], ['x3', 'x1']]
```

As you can see a new sublist is added at each step, how can I replace them with a new name and new appropriate weight?

Comment: A `list` is a single dimension untyped array, it holds no weights. You can either keep a separate `list` with corresponding weights for the same index, or you can make your list elements tuples/lists/objects where one element will contain the element value and the other its weight.

Comment: You actually have 3 questions here and they are too open ended. Consider editing and focusing on one.

Comment: @zwer Thanks how would you make such connection between two lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the weight, you can use a tuple for each element of your list:
(name,weight)

```
aList = [('x1',1),('x2',1),('x3',1),('x4',1)]
```

now you can access to the weight of 'x3' like:

```
print(aList[2][1]) # --> 1
```

And then you can do:

```
def randMerge(l:list, count:int, name) -> list:
  tmp = random.sample(l,k=count)
  sum = 0
  for x in tmp:
    sum += x[1]
  l.append((name,sum))
  return l
```

Or with dynamic names:

```
def randMerge(l:list, count:int) -> list:
  tmp = random.sample(l,k=count)
  sum = 0
  for x in tmp:
    sum += x[1]
  l.append(("x"+str(len(l)+1),sum))
  return l
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I run the code I get the Error: randMerge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name', I can see that in def you added name, what does it do exactly?

Comment: I added a 'name' parameter so you can choose the name of the new element.
newList = randMerge(newList,num,"x5")

Comment: Oh I see. So now we have a new name "x5" but now every new elements is being called "x5", is it possible to have it such that everytime a new element is added we call it a new name? "x5", "x6" and etc with the appropriate weight?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works just perfect now :)